# How to use a noncopyable object as a slot with boost::signals2::signal

Tags: boost, boost-signals2

I have an instance of a noncopyable object, that I want to use with a boost signal2. The connect method expects my functor to be copyable. Is there a way to work this around? How do I remove the comment in the code below?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

struct Noncopyable
{
  Noncopyable() {};
  void operator()() { std::cerr << "hi Noncopyable" << std::endl; }
 private:
  Noncopyable(Noncopyable const&);
};

int main(void)
{
  Noncopyable no_copy;
  boost::signals2::signal<void ()> sig;
  //sig.connect(no_copy);
  sig();
}
```

Is there a way to pass a reference to `no_copy` object into `connect` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boost::ref`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/ref.html) (or `std::ref`) function to pass such an object by reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <boost/ref.hpp>

struct Noncopyable
{
  Noncopyable() {};
  void operator()() { std::cerr << "hi Noncopyable" << std::endl; }
 private:
  Noncopyable(Noncopyable const&);
};

int main(void)
{
  Noncopyable no_copy;
  boost::signals2::signal<void ()> sig;
  sig.connect(boost::ref(no_copy));
  sig();
}
```

Of course, ensure that `no_copy` object lives at least as long as it's connected to `sig`.